# DateTime comparison and Delay

Tags: c#

Assume I have this pseudo code

```
int delayMinutes = 30;

while(booleanExp)
    foreach(Fruit f in fruits)
    {
        if(f.DateTimeA > f.DateTimeB)
        {
            //doStuff
        }
    }
    //stuff
}
```

Timezones for `DateTimeA` and `DateTimeB` are equal (`TimeZoneX`, we don't know which time zone it is), but it might not be equal to `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` (`TimeZoneY`).

Basically, I want it to go inside `if` only if `((f.DateTimeA > f.DateTimeB) && (TimeZoneX.Now - f.DateTimeA - delayMinutes > 0))`. But here we don't have access to `TimeZoneX.Now`. So, if this is not possible can we do next:

If `(f.DateTimeA > f.DateTimeB)` is true, delay `doStuff` by `delayMinutes`. I tried `Threed.Sleep(DelayMinutes*60*1000)` , but that will delay next iteration for `foreach`. Can we somehow not delay next iterations?

**Note**: doStuff is an Event, if that helps

Comment: I don't think this is much of an improvement on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632443/add-a-delay-without-thread-sleep#comment105427320_59632443), unfortunately.  It looks basically the same.

Comment: You can convert both dates to UTC and compare them

Comment: Use `DateTimeOffset` instead

Comment: If you want to do anything that explicitly involves time zones, your best options are to ensure everything is in UTC (i.e. get rid of them before calculating) or to use `DateTimeOffset`. `DateTime` on its own carries no time zone information, and if you have to compare `DateTime`s from different time zones, you will be unable to by simple virtue of lacking necessary data.

Comment: I can't use DateTimeOffset, since I don't know TimeZoneX, and I can't change that for Fruit either

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski , to use the logic I need to know TimezoneX.Now, but i don't know TimeZoneX

Comment: Perhaps you're looking to do something with what `f.DateTimeB - f.DateTimeA` gives you, which is the absolute difference between these times. You cannot involve either time in a calculation with a time in a different time zone. Your problem seems either poorly worded, or outright unsolvable.

Comment: @JeroenMostert , yeah, but that doesn't help with delayMinutes, I want it to go inside "if" only if delayMinutes elapsed since DateTimeA

Comment: And how do you plan to do that? Here's `DateTimeA`: 12:00 in an unknown time zone. Here's `DateTime.Now`: 17:47 in UTC+2. How could we ever know how many minutes have passed since `DateTimeA` if we do not know the time zone of `DateTimeA`? It could be 5 hours and 47 minutes, or 47 minutes, or 4 hours and 17 minutes, or...

Comment: @JeroenMostert , that was my assumption in post that we can't do that, that's why in second part I asked how to delay without delaying next iteration

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for in that part either. It sounds like you want to delay, but only once -- you can easily do that by setting a flag and checking it in every iteration (`if (!haveDelayed) { Thread.Sleep(...); haveDelayed = true; }`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert , yeah, but assume in first iteration, it sleeps ..., second iteration has to wait until Sleep is over. I was wondering is it possible to make it sleep, so that it doesn't delay second interation

Comment: So, once the condition `f.DateTimeA > f.DateTimeB` is met you want to wait 30 minutes before executing `doStuff`? And you can't change `Fruit`? Maybe... create an instance of `Dictionary<Fruit, DateTimeOffset>` outside of the `while` loop that tracks when the condition was met for each instance of `Fruit`? Then, inside of the `if` statement go to the `Dictionary`, find the `DateTimeOffset` associated with that instance of `Fruit` and check if `delayMinutes` have elapsed since `DateTimeOffset.Now`?